# Upper limit of confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, survival

The estimated median response duration was 17.5 months (range, 0.0 to 19.6; 95% confidence interval [CI], 15.8 to not reached).

The above is taken from a medical study. Why was the upper limit of the confidence interval not reached? What does that mean

Comment: Presumably the response durations are censored - not every subject responded over the duration of the study.

Comment: This question means two different things depending on whether quotation marks are intended: are you asking why the upper limit of the CI was not attained (and in what sense it was not attained) or are you asking why it was labeled as "not reached"?